# XCode debugging (GDB) randomly hangs while stepping through code

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, gdb

After running into this issue for the 10 billionth time and nearly whipping my mac air out the window in frustration, I've decided to break down and ask if anyone else has run into this...

Environment: running the latest version of XCode (as of this question: 4.2, build 4C199) for an iOS 4.2+ application (universal app).

It appears that GDB randomly decides to completely hang while stepping through lines of code. This has happened to me now on multiple codebases, and in various locations throughout each codebase. The stepping process hangs on an arbitrary point and requires that the running iOS simulator or on-device process be stopped and restarted. Typically, after restarting my debugging session I am able to get to a different arbitrary point in stepping into/thru -- sometimes even enough to actually debug my code entirely (gasp).

I tried wiping my drive, re-installing a fresh copy of Mac OS X 10.6.8 and the aforementioned XCode... No difference.

I tried switching debuggers to LLDB; this resolved the hanging issue, but I'm not as big a fan of LLDB and prefer to use my environment as close to stock as possible.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If GDB is still hanging after reinstalling your OS and your SDK, it may be a design issue with your particular code.  Does this happen with other projects?

If it makes you feel any better, Apple is moving to LLDB as the stock debugger for Xcode, probably due to issues like your aforementioned issue.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Tim. If it were a design issue with my code base, I'd think it would be due to timer/async events that could be executing on separate threads... Does GDB stop on all threads when hitting a breakpoint?

Comment: I'm uncertain.  To my knowledge it will stop *a* thread on its own but I'm not sure if that halts *all* threads.  From a debugging point of view both scenarios would make sense...

Comment: Well, I havent discovered a solution to this maddening problem, but I'm grateful for your response. As you mentioned that Apple will be switching to LLDB as the standard debugger, and LLDB doesn't exhibit the problem, I'll give you credit for resolving (more, "informing me of the resolution") to the problem. Cheers.